# Java ArrayLists

Tags: java, classcastexception

I'm trying to run a program I have made in Java, but I don't know what is happening that it
is giving me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

Here is the code:

```
 public static ArrayList connections(ArrayList list3) {

        ArrayList connections = new ArrayList();
        int row1 = 1;
        int row2 = 0;
        int col = 0;

        connections.add(new ArrayList());
        ((ArrayList)connections.get(0)).add(0);
        ((ArrayList)connections.get(0)).add(1);

        System.out.print(((ArrayList)connections.get(0)).get(0));

        while(row1 < list3.size()) {


            if(((ArrayList)list3.get(row1)).get(col).equals(((ArrayList)connections.get(row2)).get(col))){
                connections.add(((ArrayList)list3.get(row1)).get(1));
                row1++;
            }

            else {
                connections.add(new ArrayList());
                connections.add(((ArrayList)list3.get(row1)).get(0));
                row2 = row1;
                row1++; 
            }
        }

        return connections;
     }
```

It seems that the error is in the if statement. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: If you look at the stack trace of your exception, it should show you in which line the error is. This helps in finding the mistake.

Comment: Using [generics](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/generics-136597.html) will help you avoid these errors.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(((ArrayList)list3.get(row1)).get(col).equals(((ArrayList)connections.get(row2)).get(col))){
```

should read

```
if(((ArrayList)list3.get(row1)).get(col).equals(( ((ArrayList)connections).get(row2)).get(col))){
```

You are casting connections.get(row2) instead of casting connections first and then doing a get on the arraylist.

EDIT -- You should definitely refactor the code to use Java 1.5 functionality aka generics. If that's not an option, you should refactor the code to be more readable -- for example : your method is called "connections" and then your variable is called "connections"

Answer (score 2):

You should also use generics instead of casting. That way you will get an error at compile-time if you do this and your code will be type-safe. Generics just specify the type you are using to the compiler so it can check the types at compile-time.

Example:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
list.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

list.get(0).add(0);
list.get(0).add(1);
list.get(0).add(2);
```

More about [generics here.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Hope this helps.